# I can't flag this duplicates

Tags: support

**Somehow SE is not letting me to search for this specific questions which are duplicates:**

- [Why is Photoshop's pixel grid smaller than my actual pixels?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38599/why-is-photoshops-pixel-grid-smaller-than-my-actual-pixels)
- [Why is my grid not aligning properly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26610/why-is-my-grid-not-aligning-properly?rq=1)
- [Pixel grid and Grid don't align in Photoshop CC (PS CS6 provided as a reference)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35706/pixel-grid-and-grid-dont-align-in-photoshop-cc-ps-cs6-provided-as-a-reference/38604#38604)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you marked this as a bug?  What I'm getting at in regards to searching is if you use the tags as: [`[adobe-photoshop][grids]`](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop+grids) or any other tag related to a question you should get your results.  If you click on the link above I see all three of the questions you link in your question.

Comment: I marked this as a bug because when I search for _grid align_ inside the flag menu (duplicate search), I don't get those questions.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that.  I would recommend searching for the question, if you find one, copy the address and paste it in the flag.  It should populate and you can then mark it.  Trying to filter search in the flag would be complicated.